# Observing number of selected cells in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, key-value-observing

I want to use KVO to be notified when the number of selected cells in a UICollectionView changes. When I tried to subclass `UICollectionView` and add a new property `nSelectedCells`, I ran into a problem when trying to add the logic that updates `nSelectedCells`. There are too many places where the selected cells count can change:

- Programmatically - View: `deselectItemAtIndexPath`, `selectItemAtIndexPath`, `reloadData`, ...
- UI - Controller: `didDeselectItemAtIndexPath`, `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`
- More?

What would be the best way to keep track of this value. Preferably from within the `UICollectionView` subclass.

Comment: Incrementing/decrementing in `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:`, `collectionView:didDeelectItemAtIndexPath:` should cover all places IMO.

Comment: @Drux These methods aren't automatically called if the cell is selected/deselected programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

`UICollectionViewCell` has a `selected` property.  You could override the setter for this method, as it's the only thing guaranteed to be called when a cell's selection status is changed.

Perhaps subclass a `UICollectionView` with a property to keep a counter of selected cells and register for notifications fired by your `UICollectionViewCell` subclasses in `setSelected:` based on whether the cells was selected or deselected.

As a note, just because `setSelected:` was called doesn't mean the selection status has changed.

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected {
    if (super.selected != selected) {
        if (selected) {
            // cell was unselected and became selected, increase counter
        } else {
            // cell was selected and become unselected, decrease counter
        }
    }
    super.selected = selected;
}
```

Comment: `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"CellSelected" object:self];` and `@"CellDeselected"`.  Just register for these notifications in your collection view (and unregister in `dealloc`).  `NSNotificationCenter` is plenty easy and there are plenty of quick examples available on StackOverflow/Google search.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676398/how-to-post-and-receive-an-notification

Comment: Well that sounds like too much. To keep track of CollectionView state I have to go through its subviews + global notifications. There goes encapsulation. I hoped there is a cleaner way. thanks.

Comment: Yeah.  The unfortunate thing is though, a cell can actually be selected without going through the collection view at all, nevermind all the ways to do it while going through the collection view.  All anyone needs is a reference to the cell, and then it's easy as `cell.selected = YES;`

Comment: But the collection still has to have a way of keeping track of `indexPathsForSelectedItems`. If it doesn't then using `cell.selected = YES` is not a proper usage of a `UICollectionViewCell`.

Comment: It doesn't have to keep track though.  It can easily iterate through all of the index paths and add them to the array it's going to return if the cell's `selected` property is `YES`.

Comment: I don't think it can. AFAIK, cells get reused once they go off screen.

Answer (score 0):

use a `NSMutableSet` to track selected cell's index path, when select a cell, add its indexPath to set; deselect a cell, remove its index path from set.

The collection view calls these methods only when the user successfully selects/deselect an item in the collection view. It does not call the method when you programmatically set the selection/deselection.

```
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableSet *selectedCellIndexPathsSet;

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //do some things.
    [self.selectedCellIndexPathsSet addObject:indexPath];
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //do some thing.
    [self.selectedCellIndexPathsSet removeObject:indexPath];
}
```

Comment: @Xyand Yes, you could directly add object to NSMutableSet or remove object from it, but why you do this? If you meant" - Programmatically - View: deselectItemAtIndexPath, selectItemAtIndexPath, reloadData", these don't work on the NSMutableSet.