# Send a signal from one class to a view controller or trigger a function when a UITextField is filled

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitextfielddelegate

I have a class I call InputView that is a subclass of `UIView` that contains a `UITextField` and a `UILabel`. Due to how my InputView is designed, I have it implement the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol so I can do a bunch of things when its `UITextField` is edited.

I then have a View Controller that has multiple InputView's in it. I want to create a new InputView whenever the first InputView in the VC is filled up. Now I could do this using a simple check in the function that is called when a `UITextField` ends editing, and just check if the InputView is filled up or not, but as I said, InputView already implements the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol.

I want to "send" a signal from an InputView, that I can catch in my VC and then run a function that creates a new InputView. If you're confused, see the following image:
[image]

Comment: You can use a delegation pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use notification to trigger an action in you View Controller.

Use this answer
[How to post and receive an notification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676398/how-to-post-and-receive-an-notification)